# how to parse xml tags containing '-' in their name?

Tags: php, xml, parsing

i can't parse the tags containing "-" in their name in php with simplexml.

this is the xml-
     http://synd.cricbuzz.com/score-gadget/gadget-scores-feed.xml

the url-text and url-link could not be parsed.following errors accoured-
1)Use of undefined constant text - assumed 'text' in C:\wamp\www\score1.php 
2)Use of undefined constant link - assumed 'link' in C:\wamp\www\score1.php
3)2)Use of undefined constant link - assumed 'url' in C:\wamp\www\score1.php
plz help me
php is parsing the url-text as seprate variables-"url" and "text"

this is the code

```
<?php 
    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); Header('Pragma: no-cache');

    $url = "http://synd.cricbuzz.com/score-gadget/gadget-scores-feed.xml";
    //$url = "C:\wamp\www\score.xml";
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec ($curl);
    curl_close ($curl);
    print $result;
    $fp = fopen('score.xml', 'w');
    if($fp)
        fwrite($fp,  $result);  
    else
    echo "Error !";

    $url = "score.xml";
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url,null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
     foreach ($xml->match as $xmlinfo):
        $header=$xmlinfo->header;
        $description=$xmlinfo->description;
        $urltext=$xmlinfo->url-text;
        $urllink=$xmlinfo->url-link;
        echo $header,$description,$urltext;
    endforeach;
    //var_dump($xml);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Accessing elements within an XML document that contain characters not
>   permitted under PHP's naming convention (e.g. the hyphen) can be
>   accomplished by encapsulating the element name within braces and the
>   apostrophe.

In your case:

```
$xmlinfo->{'url-text'}
```

[**Live DEMO.**](https://eval.in/36754)

[**Source Example #3**](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)